# Need to get name of product from previous page Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, forms, product-page, magento2.2.4

I had a Request A Quote button on certain product pages on my Magento 1.9 site and when clicked, it would bring users to a custom contact form which would have the Product Name field filled in with the name of the product they came from.

I done it in Magento 1.9 using the below on the custom contacts forms `.phtml` page:

```
<form method="post">
    <?php $productName = $_POST['productname'];?>
</form>
```

Then using `$productName` in the field where needed.

How would I achieve this in Magento 2.2?

Comment: Please add code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage it like below:

Create a link with product id like http://example.com/quote-page?id=4 where 4 is the product id.

```
<a href="http://example.com/quote-page?id=4">Request A Quote</a>
```

When user click "Request a Quote" link then it will be redirected to quote page when you can get the product id by request parameter and then you can load the product name and show according to your requirement.

Comment: I have generated the url based on the product ID so on my product with ID 3310 the Request a Quote link is generating this link: mydomain.com/request-a-quote/id/3310 but it sends me to a 404 page

Comment: mydomain.com/request-a-quote/ this url is working fine?

Comment: Yes, that link is working fine

Comment: Then you can try like my updated answer.

Comment: That done the trick, thanks very much for your help

Comment: Happy to Help!...